# C program - little endian example - error

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I am working on an example from book - CSPP - O'Hallaron & Bryant

on compile time i get an error -

`gcc -Wall -W -Werror main.c -o endianc`

also tried with `cc main.c` - same error

```
aaron@aaron-Box:~/xxx/cpp/endian$ cc main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:24: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘byte_pointer’
 typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;
                    ^
 main.c:8:17: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘byte_pointer’
 void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int len) 
             ^
main.c:17:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
main.c:22:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
 main.c:27:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
 main.c:6:24: error: declaration for parameter ‘byte_pointer’ but no such parameter
 typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;
                    ^
 main.c:29:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
```

actual program -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;

void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int len) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void show_int(int x) 
{
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}

void show_float(float x) 
{
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(float));
}

void show_pointer(void *x) 
{
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(void *));
}
return 0;
}
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have fixed it now

replaced `int main(void);` with `int main()` notice NO simicolon -> i used it from this tutorial -> [URL](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C/C%2B%2B-Program-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

and also replaced `return 0;` with `return (0);` notice the parenthesis with return.

i also noticed the examples in "c Programming Language" D.Richie -> example with `main` method do not include `;`

1) can i please ask what are these variations in code ?

2) now i can not run the program `./endianc` -> it has no response

i also tried

```
xx@aaron-Box:~/xxx/cpp/endian$ cc main.c
xx@aaron-Box:~/xxx/cpp/endian$ a out
a: command not found
```

(do i need to open separate thread for this problem?)

thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the semicolon `;` after `void main()`. (Also, it seems unlikely that you would need that line in the first place, but you need the actual implementation of the `main` function, and it has a return type of `int`, not `void`.)

Comment: -> changed int main(void);  from void main() - now the error appears as 
**main.c:5:2: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
  {
  ^**

Comment: @kasper_341 Move the whole `int main(void) {` to right before `return 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Missing semicolon at main() that is why it is throwing the error.

Comment: -> checked semicolon -

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because "void main()" is immediately followed by typedef. The entire body of the main function is missing. Go back and check the book, and see what you left out.

Comment: -> checked the example again, i don't see anything left out ?

Comment: Must be a typo in the book , then. It happens!